# Extract columns sequentially to add to layers name of rasterbrick using setNames in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame of two columns of 6 rows. I want to add the vectors of each column assigned to the layer names of 2 raster bricks sequentially. To explain

I have a list of raster brick (for this example 2) each raster files have six layers, and their names are shown as index.1, index.2, index.3.....index.6

[data2 list of raster bricks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HusCg.png)

I have a list
[list y for names](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wUk0n.png)

Now I am using `pblapply` to `setNames` of layers of the raster brick e.g,.

`NewName <- pblapply(data2, function(file){ setNames(file, y[,1]})`

using `y[,1]` sets the layers names of the 2 bricks to column 1 which is wrong as shown below.

[Wrongly named raster layer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O1WbA.png)

I want for rasterbrick 1 the layer names to be of 2003_07_ag412_mlrc , and for rasterBrick 2 to be 2003_08_ag412_mlrc.  This is for a 2-set raster brick I have many for the last 20 years.

Any help is appreciated